# nodejs try catch and res.status usage

Tags: node.js, express

i am still not so happy about my code in regards to structuring of try/catch and res.status.
I guess the catch block will never reached when an error within the request is coming back as response right ?
What is the best way to structure this, i am only interested in giving back the correct res.status in regards to the occuring error ??

```
setPublicLink: async (req, res, next) => {

    try{
        console.log('Entering setPublicLink');

        var mytoken = "Bearer "+process.env.MY_TOKEN;

        request({
                url: ' https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
                headers: {
                  'content-type' : 'application/octet-stream',
                  'authorization' : mytoken
                },
                encoding: null,
                method: 'POST',
                body: fs.createReadStream(fileItem.path),
                encoding: null
               }, (error, response, body) => {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        console.log(response);
                        //return res.status(401).json({error: 'Upload of file was not successful.'});
                    } else if ( response.statusCode == 200) {
                        //nothing to do
                    } else {
                        console.log(response);
                        return res.status(401).json({error: 'Upload of file was not successful.'});
                    }
               });

        request({
            url: 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings',
            headers: {
                'content-type' : 'application/json',
                'authorization' : mytoken
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(reqBodyJson)
            }, (error, response, body) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log(response);
                    return res.status(401).json({error: 'Error when trying to set public link'});
                } else if ( response.statusCode == 200) {
                    return res.status(200).json({success: 'Public Link has been set successfully.'});  
                } else if ( response.statusCode == 409) {
                    return res.status(409).json({error: 'Nothing to set. Public link already exists.'});  
                } else {
                    return res.status(401).json({error: 'Could not set public link'});
                }
            });

    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('Error Occured : '+ err);
        return res.status(401).json({error: 'Error occured trying to set publicLink'});
    }

},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code will never hit the `catch` block since your handling all off the errors. but your code style is difficult to maintain it is better to use promises for example you could use [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) module then your code will be somthing like if you have node 8+:

```
setPublicLink: async (req, res, next) => {
try{
    console.log('Entering setPublicLink');
    var mytoken = "Bearer "+process.env.MY_TOKEN;
    var response = await requestPromise({
            url: ' https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
            headers: {
              'content-type' : 'application/octet-stream',
              'authorization' : mytoken
            },
            encoding: null,
            method: 'POST',
            body: fs.createReadStream(fileItem.path),
            encoding: null
           });
var response1 = await requestPromise({

url: 
'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings',
            headers: {
                'content-type' : 'application/json',
                'authorization' : mytoken
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(reqBodyJson)
          });
res.send({success: 'Public Link has been set successfully.'});// it sends 200 automatically
    }
catch(ex){
res.sendStatus(401);
}
    }
```

also you can get the response headers.

Comment: OK i will look how i can map my code to the request-promise module you mentioned.
If i would not handle the errors, will my code reach than the catch block ?

Comment: yes in this case your code will hit the catch block and it will be a lot easier to read, debug and maintain